# Нужна ли запятая перед КАК: "...становится моментально(,) как глыба..."

Tags: пунктуация, как

Нужна ли запятая перед ***как*** в предложении?

*Этот скромный человек становится моментально, как глыба, как скала, когда нужно отстаивать позиции России.*

Comment: @М_Г Если быть точным (для заголовка), то надо так: _становится моментально() как глыба_... Мне кажется, что присутствует в этом определённый нюанс...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова По-моему, и без "моментально", и с ним запятая не нужна. В чем тогда нюанс?

Comment: ЭТО (про отсутствие запятой) — ВАШЕ мнение, а ведь, вполне возможно, есть и другие...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, Изменил заголовок (раз есть такое мнение - пусть будет отражено в заголовке).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно:

***Этот скромный человек становится моментально как глыба, как скала, когда нужно отстаивать позиции России.***

Запятая перед ***как глыба*** не нужна. Сравнительные обороты *как глыба, как скала*  входят в состав составного именного сказуемого ***становится как глыба, как скала*** (здесь *становится* — полузнаменательная связка).

См. [**ПАС:**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125)

> **§ 90.** Обороты со сравнительными союзами (частицами) ***как, словно, будто, точно, как будто, что*** не выделяются запятыми в
>   следующих случаях:
>
> а) при сказуемом, требующем конкретизации (оборот имеет значение
>   отождествления или приравнивания)...

Comment: Он стоял как громом пораженный. В этом предложении тоже не надо запятой? Отсутствие запятой тоже объясняется этим же правилом?

Comment: У Розенталя: "Он сидел как громом поражённый" в п. 4 "...оборот образует именную часть составного сказуемого или по смыслу тесно связан со сказуемым"  (http://modernlib.ru/books/rozental_ditmar_elyashevich/spravochnik_po_russkomu_yaziku_punktuaciya/read_15/) По моему, здесь именно "тесно связан со сказуемым".

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятая нужна, это сравнительный оборот.

Comment: Становится глыбообразен, нет сравнения. )))